# JAVACC ERROR choice conflict in (...)* construct

Tags: compiler-errors, bnf, javacc

i am using javacc for the first time.

I keep getting this error :

```
Warning: Choice conflict in (...)* construct at line 35, column 43.
     Expansion nested within construct and expansion following construct
     have common prefixes, one of which is: <SPACE>
     Consider using a lookahead of 2 or more for nested expansion.
```

I've looked into this and found out it is due to a choice which the parser does not know which is the most appropriate.

```
void l_zero() : {} {
 TOKEN1 ( TOKEN2 TOKEN1)*  
}
```

The error arrises  just before the `(` in this line, could any one help me understand this properly please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have (I think)

```
void l_zero() : {} {
    <TOKEN1> ( <SPACE> <TOKEN1> )*  
}
```

The problem is that a `<SPACE>` can follow an `l_zero`. For example, there might be a production like this somewhere

```
void someNonterminal() : {} {
    l_zero() <SPACE> <YETANOTHERTOKEN>
}
```

Suppose the remaining input when `l_zero` starts is

```
<SOMETOKEN> <SPACE> ...
```

After consuming the `<SOMETOKEN>` the parser needs to decide whether to enter the loop or return from `l_zero`. It can't decide on the basis of the next token. This is what the error message is telling you.

---

What to do?

Is it the case that any space that follows a `l_zero` can not be followed by a `<TOKEN1>`? If so the parser can decide whether to enter the loop based on the next two tokens.  You can resolve the conflict with either of the following:

```
void l_zero() : {} {
    <TOKEN1> ( LOOKAHEAD(2) <SPACE> <TOKEN1> )*  
}
```

or

```
void l_zero() : {} {
    <TOKEN1> ( LOOKAHEAD(<SPACE> <TOKEN1>) <SPACE> <TOKEN1> )*  
}
```